# How to change the parametric equations of the curtate cycloid to set the initial point

Tags: cycloid

I know that the parametric equations of the curtate cycloid of radius b and fixed point at the distance $a<b$ from the center of the circle are
$$x(t)=at-b\cdot\sin{t}$$
$$y(t)=a-b\cdot\cos{t}$$
But with these equations the starting point is under the centre of the circle. If I want it above the centre, how can I modify these two equations?
Do I only have to change the second in 
$$y(t)=a+b\cdot\cos{t}$$ or may I have to change something else?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to tell us what these equations are ... & then repeat the title so we know what your question is ?

Answer (score 1):

If you start with the point above the center, as the wheel rolls it move forward faster at the start, so the equations should be 
$$x(t)=at+b\sin t\\y(t)=a+b\cos t$$
This corresponds to making the change $t \to t+\pi$ to rotate the circle, then resetting the zero of $x$ to where $a \pi$ was.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. another question, if possible: how does it change the formula to calculate its length if the starting point change as described? It is not equal, isn't it?

Comment: The new $t$, which is $\phi$ in the Mathworld article is $t-\pi$, so the formula given there would give you the arc length from $t=\pi$ to somewhere.  That is because $t=\pi$ is the bottom of an arc.  If you want the arc length from $t_1$ to $t_2$ you can use that formula to get the length from $t=\pi$ to $t=t_1$ and from $t=\pi$ to $t=t_2$ and subtract.